# Is there a way to map common Mac keyboard shortcuts to windows?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, synergy

I dual box windows and mac side by side.  Switching between the two OS's via a single keyboard can be a minor annoyance when it comes to key combinations.  Parallels has a wonderful feature where common keys are [mapped to the windows OS](http://blog.parallels.com/2015/07/14/using-keyboard-shortcuts-with-parallels-desktop-for-mac/).  Is there a program or mechanism that I can do this on a pure windows box?  I'm using [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy/) to control the windows machine from a mac keyboard. The most important key sequence to solve is copy-paste/cut.

Bonus points if you can tell me how to install this only on a hyper-v hosted VM.  (I don't want the host OS to be impacted by this change because I use this OS for playing games...not for work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synergy has the ability to remap keys out of the box.

On the MacOS server machine, stop the server process then click on "Configure Server". Double click on the screen that you want to remap the keys for, then on the right side of the panel Remap "Ctrl" to "Super" and vice-versa. Close off all of the popup windows, hit apply the start the server process.